# Need assistance with running the Map reduce WordCount job with data that is stored on amazon s3

Tags: java, hadoop, amazon-s3, mapreduce

I am trying to run the Map reduce WordCount job on a text file that I have stored in my bucket on Amazon s3. I have set up all the required the required authentication for the map reduce framework to communicate with Amazon, but I keep on running with this error. Any idea why this is happening?

```
13/01/20 13:22:15 ERROR security.UserGroupInformation:
PriviledgedActionException as:root
cause:org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: Input path does
not exist: s3://name-bucket/test.txt
Exception in thread "main"
org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: Input path does not
exist: s3://name-bucket/test.txt
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:197)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:208)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.writeOldSplits(JobClient.java:989)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.writeSplits(JobClient.java:981)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.access$600(JobClient.java:174)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:897)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:850)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:416)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1121)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:850)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJob(JobClient.java:824)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.runJob(JobClient.java:1261)
    at org.myorg.WordCount.main(WordCount.java:55)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:156)
```

Comment: Are you sure your input exists and that you put the right bucket name? Have you tried with "s3n" instead of "s3"?

Comment: Thanks that worked, I replace s3 to s3n in both the input url and hadoop-site.xml. Do you know why this worked and just s3 did not?

Comment: I added more details in an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You actually have to replace the protocol `s3` by `s3n`. These are 2 different filesystems with different properties:

- **s3n is the s3 Native Filesystem**: A native filesystem for reading and writing regular files on S3. The advantage of this filesystem is that you can access files on S3 that were written with other tools. Conversely, other tools can access files written using Hadoop. The disadvantage is the 5GB limit on file size imposed by S3. For this reason it is not suitable as a replacement for HDFS (which has support for very large files).
- **s3 is the Block filesystem**: A block-based filesystem backed by S3. Files are stored as blocks, just like they are in HDFS. This permits efficient implementation of renames. This filesystem requires you to dedicate a bucket for the filesystem - you should not use an existing bucket containing files, or write other files to the same bucket. The files stored by this filesystem can be larger than 5GB, but they are not interoperable with other S3 tools.

([source](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/AmazonS3))

In your case your bucket is probably using `s3n` filesystem, I believe it's the default, most of the buckets I use are also `s3n`. So you should use `s3n://name-bucket/test.txt`